# I am not able to open camera on my framework 7 V3 (Nectar Template) through Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: cordova, camera, html-framework-7

I have tried all the codes and guides over the internet to open camera on a click of camera icon but unable to do so. Using Framework 7 (Nectar Template) and cordova camera plugin.

```html
<script>

    return {
        
        methods: {

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            var self=this;
        self.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        document.getElementById("cameraTakePicture").addEventListener 
   ("click", cameraTakePicture); 
   
    
    },  
                                
       cameraTakePicture: function() { 
        var self=this;
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {  
      quality: 50, 
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
   });  
  
   },
   onSuccess: function(imageData) { 
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage'); 
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; 
   },  
   
    onFail: function(message) { 
      app.dialog.alert('Failed because: ' + message); 
   } 

                                    
    },
    on: {
        pageInit: function() {
                var self=this;
                window.addEventListener('deviceready', self.onDeviceReady, false)
                
            }
                
}
}
  

 
</script>
```

Above is my js and it gives no error but camera is not working If click on button

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you double check code you've posted? It looks like it is commented out (/* and */)

Comment: please check now